# Facebook Invite to Canvas, how to get PageID from Invite URL

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm using Facebook Requests ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/ ) to invite people from my Page Tab App to my Page Tab App. I needed to create a canvas that this works. Now I want to redirect the people, who click on the Invite and land on my Canvas URL, to my page tab url. But I need to fetch the pageID, to redirect them.

Can I do a signed-request in my canvas and fetch the PageID from the users invite request? If yes, how?

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that requests are only available for canvas games.

Comment: This is a correct statement, but it in no way attempts to answer the question.

Comment: What I meant was that if you try to go around that rule the risk of your app is getting removed is pretty high